# Save output to another directory when output was made with cell2csv

Tags: matlab, csv, save, cell

I am using the FileExchange code [cell2csv](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7601-cell2csv) to save a cell in my code. I'd like the output file, the csv file, to be saved to a different directory. How can that be done?

Here's my current code for saving the cell:

```
cell2csv([fname(13:16), '-', u_id{k}, '_24hrBlkAvg.csv'], site_data, '\t'); % cell2csv(filename,cellArray,delimiter)
```

Comment: I don't know if I get you correct, but since this function calls `fopen` you can simply add an (**existing**) path to `filename`, e.g. `path_to_file/file.csv`. Can be both, relative and absolute paths.

Comment: Not sure how to implement that. I tried this `path = '/d9/archive/jg3223/US/O3/CSV_Files';
            filename = [fname(13:16), '-', u_id{k}, '_24hrBlkAvg.csv'];
            cell2csv(path/filename, site_data, '\t');` and was told `Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree`. It seems like MATLAB is treating `/` as a division sign.

Comment: Just make a string cat. `cell2csv([path '/' filename], site_data, '\t');`

Comment: Thanks! You could write this up as an answer.

Comment: Well, there is already an accepted answer that works. That should be sufficient here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `fullfile` to construct your path in a system-independent way

```
%// do not put everything in one line, the code should be readable to human:
filename = [fname(13:16), '-', u_id{k}, '_24hrBlkAvg.csv'] 
filepath = fullfile(beetroot_folder, daughter_folder, subsubfolder, filename)
cell2csv(filepath, site_data, '\t');
```

if you need to save in a subfoder, use `'.'` for your current folder, 
or for saving in a sister folder use `'..'` for parent folder:

```
filepath = fullfile('.', filename)
```